# Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: reactjs

In my **app.js** I want to check if first the user is logged in and want it to direct me to the URL picked. If not, I want it to automatically direct me to the `/connexion` URL (login page) if the user is logged in I want it then to check if the user profile is complete, if so, it should direct me to the picked URL or else I want it to direct me to the complete info page `/information`

I used to have only one check the logged in check however when I added the information check I started getting I know that the error is coming from my `useEffect` and the fact it keeps toggling in every check however I am not sure how to fix it:

this is my code:

```
const App = () => {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [tokenChecked, setTokenChecked] = useState(false);
  const { profile } = useStateContext();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const token = sessionStorage.getItem("token");
    setIsLoggedIn(token ? true : false);
    setTokenChecked(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router>
      {tokenChecked ? (
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<NavbarLayout />}>
            <Route path="/" exact element={<HomePage />} />
            <Route path="/about" exact element={<AboutPage />} />
            <Route path="/how-it-works" exact element={<HowItWorks />} />
          </Route>
          <Route element={<NoNavbarLayout />}>
            {/*<Route path="/register-type" exact element={<LoginPick />} />*/}
            <Route path="/connexion" exact element={<UserLogin />} />
            <Route path="/récupérer" exact element={<UserRecovery />} />
            <Route path="/register-user" exact element={<UserRegister />} />
            <Route
              path="/register-tech"
              exact
              element={<TechnicianRegister />}
            />
            <Route path="/register-admin" exact element={<AdminRegister />} />
          </Route>
          <Route element={<ConfirmLayout />}>
            <Route
              path="/confirmation"
              exact
              element={<AccountConfirmation />}
            />
            <Route path="/nonconnecte" exact element={<UserRedirectLMsg />} />
            <Route
              path="/validation/:id/:confirm"
              exact
              element={<AccountValidation />}
            />
          </Route>
          {isLoggedIn === true ? (
            <>
            {profile === 'finished' ? (
                <>
                  <Route element={<ConfirmLayout />}>
                    <Route path="/encours" exact element={<UserPending />} />
                    <Route
                      path="/information"
                      exact
                      element={
                        <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
                          <UserInfo />
                        </Elements>
                      }
                    />
                  </Route>
                  <Route element={<DashboardLayout />}>
                    <Route
                      path="/nouvel-appareil"
                      exact
                      element={<UserNewDevice />}
                    />
                    <Route path="/new-project" exact element={<NewProject />} />
                    <Route
                      path="/demande-contrat"
                      exact
                      element={<NewContract />}
                    />
                    <Route path="/user-dash" exact element={<UserDash />} />
                    <Route path="/profile" exact element={<UserProfile />} />
                    <Route
                      path="/user-history"
                      exact
                      element={<UserHistory />}
                    />
                    <Route path="/navigation" exact element={<Compte />} />

                    <Route
                      path="/user-notification"
                      exact
                      element={<UserNotification />}
                    />
                    <Route
                      path="/user-projets-details/:id"
                      exact
                      element={<UserProjectDetails />}
                    />
                    <Route
                      path="/user-intervention-details/:id"
                      exact
                      element={<InterventionDetail />}
                    />
                    <Route
                      path="/user-details/:id"
                      exact
                      element={<UserDetail />}
                    />
                    <Route
                      path="/user-claim-details/:id"
                      exact
                      element={<UserClaimsDetail />}
                    />
                    <Route
                      path="/reclamations"
                      exact
                      element={<UserClaims />}
                    />
                    <Route path="/browse" exact element={<SearchGrid />} />

                    <Route
                      path="/technician-dash"
                      exact
                      element={<TechnicianDash />}
                    />
                    <Route
                      path="/technician-profile"
                      exact
                      element={<TechnicianProfile />}
                    />
                    <Route
                      path="/technician-projets"
                      exact
                      element={<TechnicianProjects />}
                    />
                    <Route
                      path="/technician-history"
                      exact
                      element={<UserHistory />}
                    />
                    <Route
                      path="/technician-projets-details/:id"
                      exact
                      element={<UserProjectDetails />}
                    />
                    <Route
                      path="/product/:id"
                      exact
                      element={<UserNewProductDetail />}
                    />
                    <Route
                      path="/admin-notification"
                      exact
                      element={<AdminNotification />}
                    />
                    <Route path="/new-user" exact element={<AddUser />} />
                    <Route path="/litiges" exact element={<Litige />} />
                    <Route
                      path="/réclamations"
                      exact
                      element={<Reclamation />}
                    />
                    <Route path="/users" exact element={<UsersList />} />
                  </Route>
                  <Route element={<NoNavbarLayout />}>
                    <Route
                      path="/register-type"
                      element={<Navigate to="/navigation" />}
                    />
                  </Route>
                </>
            ):(
              <>
              <Route
                path="*"
                element={<Navigate to="/information" replace />}
              />
          </>              
            )}
            </>
          ) : isLoggedIn === false ? (
            <>
                <Route
                  path="*"
                  element={<Navigate to="/connexion" replace />}
                />
            </>
          ) : null}
        </Routes>
      ) : null}
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is caused because you are trying to render multiple Routes with the same path.

```
 <Route
                path="*"
                element={<Navigate to="/information" replace />}
              />
```

It can't access the information route because the profile is not completed yet.